# Xubuntu 18.04 install Office 365 Business with Wine fails "0040:err:seh:setup_exception stack overflow"

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-office, wine

Well, I installed wine and I tried to open Office365 installer using the code:

```
wine <file_name>
```

I received this error message:

> 0031:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is
>   outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually,
>   you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.

Then, the office installer started loading. After a while the loading page disappeared and I received another error message:

> wine: Call from 0x7b44c1e7 to unimplemented function
>   msvcp140.dll.?uncaught_exceptions@std@@YAHXZ, aborting
>   0040:err:seh:setup_exception stack overflow 1824 bytes in thread 0040
>   eip 000000007bc5dc43 esp 0000000000140ef0 stack
>   0x140000-0x141000-0x240000

I'm new to Linux so I don't know what to do.

**Edit:**

Office version: Professional Plus X64

XUbuntu version: 18.04

Comment: A VM running windows is another option, or just use LibreOffice

Comment: @Xen2050 I tried LibreOffice but for me MS office is more suitable. I also think VM consumes HD space and memory :)

Comment: A VM consumes memory only when being used. Storage space is very cheap now with 1 TB HDD costing less than 70 USD (to date) or 14 GiB per dollar.

Answer (score 7):

The volunteers who develop, test, and maintain [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) have done some testing of Office365, for Microsoft has not published instructions for Linux users nor has Microsoft released a Linux version.

The [Wine installation guide and error description](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=36167) for the 64-bit Microsoft app ('Office365 Business') has not been tested with any version of Ubuntu, only with a 2017 version of Arch Linux x64.  The least worst ('bronze' grade) results were obtained by:

- Install **MsXML6** ([winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks) msxml6).
- Set "HKCU\Software\Wine\Direct3D\MaxVersionGL" (DWORD) to "30002" (hex).
  After the installation:
- Override **riched20** to (native, builtin).
- Copy DLLs (**AppvIsvSubsystems32.dll**, **AppvIsvStream32.dll**,**C2R32.dll**) from `drive_c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/ClickToRun/` to `drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/`.

The Wine installation guide and error description for the 32-bit Microsoft app ('Office365 Personal') reflects the experience in testing with [Antergos x86_64](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35527), [Gentoo Linux x86_64](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35527&iTestingId=101537), and [Ubuntu 16.04 "Xenial" amd64](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35527&iTestingId=101121). The best results ('silver' grade) were accomplished with the latter, using these steps:

Step-by-step instructions:

- create a 32 bit Wineprefix (leave Windows version on the default **Windows 7**)
- install **riched20**, **msxml6** with [Winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks)
- in [Winecfg](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winecfg) add the **riched20**(native, builtin) and **msxml6**(native, builtin) override manually (if not added by winetricks)
- run the installer (the installation procedure is automatic)
- after the installation copy the **AppvIsvSubsystems32.dll** and the **C2R32.dll** from: /Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/ClickToRun/  to: /Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/

Comment: Still impossible to get any Office (2016, 2019, 2021) working under Wine. I tried this all.